# EF 5 one to many relationship - why is foreign key created per type of profile

Tags: entity-framework, data-annotations, code-first, one-to-many

I have the following model set up:

```
    public class User
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string UserName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public TypeOfProfile ProfileType { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string ProfileName { get; set; }
```

I don't want to use TPT. I want the user table to be the short summary table for quick loading. Once clicking on a User his profile is fetched. I have multiple types of profiles. E.g

```
public class Person | Business | Artist
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Deal> Deals { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Event> Events { get; set; }

    public virtual IList<Vacancy> Vacancies { get; set; }
```

This way I can create a profile for a certain user and give it the same Id as the User Id, hence the DatabaseGeneratedOption.None. This all works fine. But then the collections come into place: Deals, Events, Vacancies,..

```
public class Event
{
    [Key]
    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGeneratedAttribute(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    public int UserId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public int AddressId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual User User { get; set; }

    public virtual Address Address { get; set; }
```

All is created just fine with Code First except for one thing. In the Events, Deals and Vacancies table a foreign key is created for each type on top of the UserId property of Event, Deal and Vacancy.

Due to this, the model insists on having a profile of each type for the User, while I only want 1 type of profile per user:

> Column:
>
> Id (PK, int, not null)
>
> UserId (FK, int, not null)
>
> Keys:
>
> PK_dbo.Events
>
> FK_dbo.Events.dbo.Artists_UserId
>
> FK_dbo.Events.dbo.Businesses_UserId
>
> FK_dbo.Events.dbo.People_UserId
>
> FK_dbo.Events.dbo.Users_UserId
>
> ...

I only want the foreign key to the Users_Id to be created. When I delete the other fk's to people, businesses and artists, then everything is working as i want it. Like this:

> Column:
>
> Id (PK, int, not null)
>
> UserId (FK, int, not null)
>
> Keys:
>
> PK_dbo.Events
>
> FK_dbo.Events.dbo.Users_UserId
>
> ...

But how can I configure code first or by fluent API that the 3 extra foreign keys are not created. (due to the ILists of those Profiles) I don't want to be able to retrieve a profile from the event object, only the User object.

Thanks in advance!

Kr

Comment: It is not clear where `Artist` and `Business` are in this model. Are they derived from `Person`? It looks to me like `User` should have the collections, but that probably defeats its purpose.

Comment: Artist and Business are siblings from Person. There is no inheritance in the model. I've edited the code above.

Comment: I don't understand the model. What is the entity class `TypeOfProfile`  and how does it relate to `Person`, `Business` and `Artist`?

Comment: TypeOfProfile is an enum, just to indicate which controller I have to address to load the user profile.

I don't want a direct link between the user and his profile (Business, Personal, Artist) because the profiles will be a more heavy read operation. (I also want to avoid using lazy load on the user)

Therefor when I have my user, I check what kind of profile he has, and then I will load his profile from the correct controller: BusinessController, ArtistController, PersonController.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I solved my problem using a TPH architecture. (Table Per Hierarchy) Now I have only one Profile table with a discriminator for Person, Business and Artist. The primary key of my Profile table is at the same time the foreign key to my User table.

Kr